# VBA Error: Runtime Error: 9 - Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, range

**Requirement**: I need to copy 1 Column - Col G (need to determine the number of rows dynamically) from 1 Workbook to another.

**Problem**: Getting VBA Error:

> Runtime Error: 9 - Subscript out of range Please help.

```
Sub Set_Open_ExistingWorkbook()

Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me364167\Documents\Practice_OB_Status_Detailed_Report_Mainframe.xls")
'Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me364167\Documents\Practice level_Opportunity Pipeline_Mainframe.xls")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sheet1Data As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Workbooks("Practice_OB_Status_Detailed_Report_Mainframe.xls").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "G"), Cells(LastRow, "G")).Copy
Workbooks("OB Macro.xlsx").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).PasteSpecial


' Workbooks("Practice_OB_Status_Detailed_Report_Mainframe.xls").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "G"), Cells(LastRow, "G")).Copy
' Workbooks("OB Macro.xlsx").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

wkb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: try not to use `ActiveSheet` when searching for you `LastRow`, instead use referenced objects, like `With wkb.Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report")`. You are missing one parameter after the line with `PasteSpecial` , you need to add something like `PasteSpecial xlValues`

Comment: I changed the code but same result.

Comment: With wkb.Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
 
Workbooks("Practice_OB_Status_Detailed_Report_Mainframe.xls").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "G"), Cells(LastRow, "G")).Copy
Workbooks("OB Macro.xlsx").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: Workbooks("OB Macro.xlsx").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: ActiveSheet when using multiple worksheets (and even workbooks) is a bad practice and often times confuses the compiler....

Comment: Is `OB Macro.xlsx` open? Does it have a worksheet named `OB_Status_Detailed_Report`? Note that you *should* be getting a 1004 error from the unqualified use of the `Cells` global, but you probably need to fix the subscript error before you start getting that one.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps? Your ranges are not fully qualified and as Shai Rado says you are missing a PS paremeter.

```
Sub Set_Open_ExistingWorkbook()

Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me364167\Documents\Practice_OB_Status_Detailed_Report_Mainframe.xls")
'Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me364167\Documents\Practice level_Opportunity Pipeline_Mainframe.xls")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sheet1Data As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With wkb.Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "G"), .Cells(LastRow, "G")).Copy
End With

With Workbooks("OB Macro.xlsx").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, "A")).PasteSpecial xlValues
End With

' Workbooks("Practice_OB_Status_Detailed_Report_Mainframe.xls").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "G"), Cells(LastRow, "G")).Copy
' Workbooks("OB Macro.xlsx").Worksheets("OB_Status_Detailed_Report").Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

wkb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, Doug And Conmintern - You guys rock. Thanks a lot.